# How do I set the sensitivity on an email in c#?

Tags: c#, system.net.mail

Is there a way to set the sensitivity on an email in c#? I tried using

```
mail.Headers.Add("Sensitivity", "Confidential");
```

but nothing shows up on the email.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [RFC 1327](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1327), the accepted values for the `Sensitivity` header are one of:

> sensitivity     = "Personal" / "Private" /
> "Company-Confidential"

So in your case, I would suggest trying:

```
mail.Headers.Add("Sensitivity", "Company-Confidential");
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it.